# Connection Status: unknown access is denied

Tags: networking, windows-vista, permissions, user-profiles

My main user profile is having problems showing stats for my network.

The Vista network connection icon has a red x in it and states, “Connection status: Unknown"  "Access is denied.”  on mouse hover, and the Network and Sharing center shows the following.

[image: Network and Sharing Center Error]

The main profile is local admin and other user profiles work. I have tried resetting permissions on my profile folder.

Comment: Verify that your NIC is functioning correctly.  Have you tried an updated driver?

Are there any errors in your event logs?

Comment: The computer is functioning 100% all other user profiles are fine.  This user profile is working and does have access to the network.  The only thing is the red X on the network tray icon and that I can’t change any settings. 

I found this KB  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945925 is doesn’t look good.

Comment: This has been tagged techsupport. serverfault isn't for general troubleshooting of personal workstations

Answer (score 2):

- Right click **Computer** and hit **Manage**
- Under **System Tools**, double click **Local Users and Groups** then click **Groups**
- Right click **Administrators**
- Click **Add to group** then click **Add** then **Advanced**
- Click **Find Now**
- Double click on **Local Service** then click **OK**
- **NT Authority\Local Service** should show up in the list, click **OK** then **Reboot**

Comment: Do you know why Local Service needs to be in this group? Something driver specific?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a permissions issue.  You can try this:

1. Go to the administrator command prompt by clicking Start
2. In the search box type "cmd" (don't hit enter yet)
3. Press CTRL + Shift + Enter (accept the UAC prompt)
4. At the `C:\Windows\system32>` prompt type:

   ```
   net localgroup Administrators "Local Service" /add (use quotes is object contains spaces)
   ```
5. Hit Enter

Answer (score 1):

@Ciaran

Sometimes **Network Location Awareness** service needs to get access by adding permissions to localservice or networkservice.

```
net localgroup administrators localservice /add
net localgroup administrators networkservice /add
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with some accounts after re-installing 64-bit Vista.  One account with the problem was "Greg". After trying several solutions from the web, I decided to get creative.  So I logged into the Administrator account, created a new account named "GregNew", then went to windows explorer and copied all files under Users\Greg to Users\GregNew.  Told it to replace all.  Then went back into manage accounts as Administrator and deleted the "Greg" account.  All is well now (for now).